# Multiple Google Sign-In for Websites buttons

Tags: javascript, google-signin

When I try to place more than one  Google Sign-In for Websites buttons (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/) on one page, I get only one button rendered, while another HTML containers for buttons staying just empty. I have NO errors on console. Is it possible to render more than one button or it is Google's restriction?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you got your client id? Are you running it from localhost?

Comment: Of course I have a client ID since I have one correctly working button. And yes, it is all about the localhost.

Comment: What happens when you place multiple of these `<div class="g-signin2" data-width="300" data-height="200" data-longtitle="true">` on the page?